# aggrid excel export completion events?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

Are there any ways we can track the progress of the excel export creation or at worse get an event when the export is done?

The browser does not support any event to check downloads that started or ended as far as I know. aggrid export feature is behind a paywall with not great docs tbh.

The other thing is that the process is really slow even for small grids and while testing I am pretty sure that the lack of any indication of the progress will make the user request an export multiple times until they see the actual file downloading which is not straight forward at all.

I tried using the processCellCallback function but even after that it takes a while to see a feedback in the UI.